# How to stop script from running with a button?

Tags: javascript

I have a script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* firework script effect */

if (typeof('addRVLoadEvent')!='function') function addRVLoadEvent(funky) {
...
}
function bang(N) {
  var i, Z, A=0;
  ....
}
function stepthrough(N) { 
.....
} 
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to stop firework</button>
```

How will I be able to make the firework script run/stop with a button click?
By default, when page loads it runs and works well.

I got the script from her http://www.mf2fm.com/rv/dhtmlfireworks.php

Comment: This is an example http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_stop

Comment: `return` from function on click of a button. Use flag to check if button pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all your javascript code in a function so that it doesn't auto run and then use the onclick method like you are right now.

Example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* firework script effect */
function myFunction() {
     script that runs firework. 
     script changing the button to run the stop function when next clicked.
} 
if (typeof('addRVLoadEvent')!='function') function addRVLoadEvent(funky) {
...
}
function bang(N) {
  var i, Z, A=0;
  ....
}
function stepthrough(N) { 
.....
} 
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click to stop firework</button>`
```